# Read NullValues from Sqlite with EF Core in .NET 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a Sqlite table with multiple columns and one of them is a nullable `INTEGER`, and I'm reading data with EF Core 5. I store here a boolean value, so the property within the entity is bool (1 == true, 0/NULL == false). I use a model conversion defined within the model builder process:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Types.Page>(entity =>
{
   ...
   entity.Property(e => e.IsPinned).HasConversion<int?>(
                        v => v ? 1 : 0, 
                        v => v.HasValue && v.Value == 1 ? true : false);
            });
   ...
}
```

That usually works, but when the data is null, I get an exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The data is NULL at ordinal 11. This method can't be called on NULL values. Check using IsDBNull before calling.

The documentation says the conversion isn't called with NULL values.

So I'm looking for a point to handle with NULL values in that way before the conversion is called. When I declare the entity property as int? it works but I want to avoid the additional conversion here (in various places). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess you only need a null check, e.g. v => v.HasValue && v.HasValue != null && v.Value == 1 ? true : false);

Comment: The problem is it doesn't reach the conversion when it is null. (I tried also ```v => v.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0 ? false : true```)

Comment: While you can change the type with value conversion, currently you can't change its nullability. So change the property type in the model to `bool?` and configure the conversion with `entity.Property(e => e.IsPinned).HasConversion<int?>()`. The other option is to use migration or similar to update the table column values in the database and make it non nullable. Then you can map `bool` model property to `int` column type using value conversion.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much.